How do I change the name of an apk that has been built in flutter
I have looked for many solutions but still the name remains the same : app-release.apk
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
variant.outputs.all { output ->
        def newApkName = "Goods Tracker.apk"
        outputFileName = newApkName
    }
}

 applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        outputFileName = "Goods Tracker.apk"
    }
}

I've tried both ways, but the result is the same :

√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-release.apk

I already specify the outputFileName, here the code :
Even though i already specify the output still same :

√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-release.apk (50.0MB)

but the below method previously worked, but after I added code or fixed my code in lib, this method doesn't work
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        def newName = "Goods Tracker.apk"
        output.outputFileName = newName
    }
}


I think you need to spcify the outputFileName in the attribute of output
output.outputFileName = "Goods Tracker.apk"

